# How to (really) empty TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I use TClientDataSet to storage some local data, by using the 'savetofile' method.

I noticed when i use the code below :

```
// at this point the file myfile.cds has 3000 records and 130 kbytes.
myClientDataSet.loadfromfile('myfile.cds');    
myClientDataSet.emptydataset;
myClientDataSet.savetofile('myfile.cds');
// at this point the file myfile.cds has no records anymore, but still has the same size, 130kb !
```

It seems the 'emptydataset' method will erase all records, but when i save to file, the file size still remains the same ! How to really erase all data and file size ?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce described behavior.

Comment: myClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates?

Comment: Note that the table structure will still be written.

Answer (score 1):

> when i save to file, the file size still remains the same ! How to really erase all data and file size ?

Using a test .CDS file of my own, I cannot reproduce your results - see comments
in the following code, which show that after `EmptyDataSet`, the (re-)saved file has a plausible, much smaller, size.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EmptyDataSetTest;
end;

procedure TForm1.EmptyDataSetTest;
var
  SourceFN,
  DestFN : String;
begin
  SourceFN := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\Data\CDSData.Cds';
  //  SourceFN file is 333709 bytes acc to a Dir command in a CMD window
  DestFN := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '\Data\DestCDSData.Cds';

  myClientDataSet.LoadFromFile(SourceFN);

  myClientDataSet.EmptyDataSet;
  myClientDataSet.SaveToFile(DestFN);

  //  DestFN file is 2268 acc to a Dir command in a CMD window
  DestFN := ChangeFileExt(DestFN, '.XML');
  myClientDataSet.SaveToFile(DestFN, dfXML);
  //  .XML file is 5128 and the file contains only the field
  //  FIELD descriptor tags under the \DATAPACKET\METADATA\FIELDS node

end;
```

So if your saved file is really the same file and filesize, it must be because
of something you have not told us in the q.  Try calling

```
myClientDataSet.Close;
myClientDataSet.Open;
```

after

```
myClientDataSet.CreateDataSet;
```